# Is there a way to set shared flag in Cocoa Pods Build schemes?

Tags: xcode6, cocoapods

I have a project which is shared between several developers.
If i run pod install, the project is created, but the build schemes are not shared.

To share the complete workspace between all devs, this build schemes must be shared.
I have the possibility to do that after creation of the workspacen.

But, is there a way to set shared flag in Cocoa Pods Build schemes automaticaly in the pod file?

Comment: did you find a way?

Answer (score 5):

For development pods, add the following to the Podfile:

```
install! 'cocoapods',
         :share_schemes_for_development_pods => true
```

Reference at https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#install_bang

I don't think it is possible for non-development pods.